# Navigation Bar back button disappears after showing an alert

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a simple view:

```
struct AccountView: View {
    @State private var showingLogoutAlert = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Log out!") {
            showingLogoutAlert = true
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingLogoutAlert, content: {
            Alert(title: Text("Log out of Flow?"),
                  primaryButton: .cancel(),
                  secondaryButton: .destructive(Text("Log out"), action: {
                //logOut()
            }))
        })
        
    }
}
```

When you tap the button, it will show an alert. The problem is, after the alert dismisses, the back button also disappears! I have no idea why this is happening. See the gif below.

[image]

I've tried to reduce the problem down to the bare minimum code. Replicated it on a separate, new app. Still the same issue.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue, all works well for me in my test, on MacOS 13.2, Xcode 14.2, tested on real ios 16.3 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
It could be different on older systems.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Running on XCode 14.1 iOS 16.1

Comment: ok, I'll show the code I used in my test. Since you don't show how you call your `AccountView`, try a new project with just my code to see if the problem persists.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine its literally wrapped in a navigation link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the working code I used in my test, on MacOS 13.2, Xcode 14.2, tested on real ios 16.3 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: AccountView()) {
                Text("AccountView")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AccountView: View {
    @State private var showingLogoutAlert = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Log out!") {
            showingLogoutAlert = true
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingLogoutAlert, content: {
            Alert(title: Text("Log out of Flow?"),
                  primaryButton: .cancel(),
                  secondaryButton: .destructive(Text("Log out"), action: {
                //logOut()
            }))
        })
    }
}
```